# activeadmin formatting error on rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I recently migrated a rails 3 app from a Mac OS X environment to a Debian server. The migration succeeded, the app is running through the WEBrick server but the formatting that had originally come with the activeadmin gem has disappeared from most views. The form is still accessible and functioning but it is in the default html formatting.

However http://domainexample.com:3000/admin still has the custom formatting, any ideas of why this has happened?

In my troubleshooting:
reinstalled activeadmin with

```
rails generate active_admin:install
```

When I run

```
rake db:migrate
```

got devise errors so dropped the databases and ran

```
rake db:create
```

rails s still works and boots the server but

rake db:migrate throws an error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'admin_users' already exists
```

UPDATE:
This fixed the problem, but I don't understand why.

had to copy the active_admin.css as active_admin.css.dup.css file from my local and upload it to the server version in app/assets/stylesheets. The server version was implementing namespaces for some reason.